# BottomNavigationView não fica na parte inferior da tela

Tags: android, android-fragment

Pessoal estou com um problema é um layout que estou desenvolvendo, esse é minha activity para cadastro de clientes e tenho somente nela um BottomNavigationView, e um LinearLayout que irei substituir por um fragment

- [ActivityCadastroCliente](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qv8YO.png)

  ```
  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/fragment_trocar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:orientation="vertical">


      <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
          android:id="@+id/bottomNavigatintoonCadastroCliente"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:layout_gravity="bottom"
          android:background="@drawable/custom_button_line"
          android:elevation="8dp"
          app:itemIconTint="@color/colorBlack"
          app:itemTextColor="@color/colorBlack"
          app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_cadastro_cliente" />
  </LinearLayout>
  ```
- FragmentCadastroCliente

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- CadastroClienteActivity.java

  ```
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.activity_cadastro_cliente);

      FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
      FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
      fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_trocar, new CadastroClienteFragment());
      fragmentTransaction.commit();
  }

  public void iniciarComponentes() {
      bottomNavigatintoonCadastroCliente = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.bottomNavigatintoonCadastroCliente);
  }
  ```

  }

O preciso fazer para corrigir meu Layout para aparecer meu BottomNavigationView na parte inferior da tela?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que é porque tu tá substituindo o conteúdo do `LinearLayout` adicionando um fragment à ele. Isto meio que remove o teu conteúdo, que no caso é o **BottomNavigationView**.

Utilize um **RelativeLayout** como root e seu problema será resolvido.

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_trocar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_above="@+id/bottomNavigatintoonCadastroCliente"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigatintoonCadastroCliente"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@drawable/custom_button_line"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/colorBlack"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/colorBlack"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_bottom_cadastro_cliente" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Isto deve funcionar normalmente. Mais uma coisa: eu adicionei dois novos atributos, que são: `layout_alignParentBottom` e `layout_above`.

O primeiro faz com que o **BottomNavigationView** alinhe-se à parte inferior do **root layout**, que é o próprio **RelativeLayout**.

O segundo faz com que o layout do fragment fique alinhado acima do **BottomNavigationView**, mas isso faz com que os itens fiquem cortados. Porém, se você deseja colocar os itens por baixo do BottomNavigationView, tu pode remover o atributo e utilizar a view `Space` no layout do teu **fragment**. Essa view `Space` precisa ter o mesmo tamanho (**height**) do **BottomNavigationView**, caso contrário, os últimos itens do **scroll** irão ficar cortados/invisíveis.

Comment: Era exatamente isso, vlw :)